# Why does `gap` add pixels to the end of a row in a grid container?

Tags: css, css-grid

I know this sounds like the typical problem of using percentage values, but it's different. At least at first glance.

Here's the situation: we have a grid with some elements:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

And the grid has a `max-width` but it's scrollable:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, max-content);  
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Let's also define how an item should be so they take up some space:

```css
.item {
  background-color: navy;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

Now, this works as expected: I can scroll to the right and I can only see the contained items inside the grid.

But if I add `gap: 5px;` to the grid and I scroll the same way, the farthest pixels to the right inside the scrollable area are suddenly not occupied by the elements. These are "extra pixels" added by the gap, somehow.

You can see it [here](https://codepen.io/manusaurio/pen/BaMvqWy).

What I've also noticed is that this only happens if there are fewer items than declared columns (e.g. if we change `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(4, max-content);` and `max-width` to `300px;` it works fine.)

Comment: wouldn't a flexbox be more suitable for this than a grid?

Comment: @BrettDonald I would and it would not. The design I've been provided is pretty unusual for way more reasons I'm willing to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `gap` is applied to the columns and rows, not the contained elements inside the grid. The grid in the snippet is 10 columns wide, and only half of them have elements "in them." The gaps are 10 pixels long, and there are 5 empty columns in a row, for a total of 50 blank pixels at the end of the grid (5 * 10 = 50.)

Answer (score 0):

**gap** adds extra space to the total width of the grid that can cause overflow and create extra space on the right side of your scrollable area, especially when the number of items is less than the number of columns specified in `grid-template-columns`.

For this, use a combination of `grid-template-columns` with `1fr` and `grid-auto-flow` with `column`, so this will create a responsive grid that adjusts the number of columns based on the container width and also grid items are filled in a column-wise manner.

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
 grid-auto-flow: column;
 max-width: 400px;
 overflow-x: auto;
 gap: 10px;
  background: cyan;
}

.gap-10 {
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: navy;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container gap-10">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```